# shiny wordcloud2 json warning and blanck page

Tags: r, shiny, wordcloud2

I have a shiny app that works perfectly fine in my laptop but when I deploy it to AWS EC2, all work except the word cloud. I want to display cloud of bigrams, trigrams and words. It displays for bigrams and trigrams but not when I choose 'words', it displays nothing. The dataframe has word and freq columns. I checked the logs and it says

> Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported, and named vectors will be translated into arrays instead of objects. If you want JSON object output, please use a named list instead. See ?toJSON.

Here is the server side code for the word cloud:

```
output$my_wordcloud <- renderWordcloud2({
req(input$file1)
req(input$token)
token = input$token
token = ifelse(token == 'words', 'word', ifelse(token == 'bigrams', 'bigram', 'trigram'))
df = to_display()
df = df %>% group_by_at(token) %>% summarise(freq = sum(Count))
df = df %>% filter(freq > 1)
wordcloud2(df, size = input$wc_size)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I dropped name attribute from my vector, which is used to build one of my dataframes, and it worked.
The issue was this line:

```
stem_completed = stemCompletion(stemmed_unique, words_corpus,"prevalent")
```

and adding the line below solved it.

```
stem_completed = unname(stem_completed)
```